# Android or iPhone application collecting payments

Tags: android, iphone

I'm starting to study a project that mainly will allows users to make payments from their iPhones or Androids. Since I don't have e-commerce experience and also I have never owned a smartphone, I ask you to give me some orientation on what is important when heading this kind of project.

**What is making me doubt**

- Is it possible to do this without Apple or Google refusing my app or charging my transactions with amounts similar to 30%?
- Is google checkout an alternative to paypal or am I getting this wrong?
- For debit card payment, what are the most common payment services in the US nowadays?
- How high is the technical complexity of that application? Is it very different to do it for iPhone and do it for Android?

**What I already know:**

- The payments have nothing to do with the application itself; this is not an in-app scenario.
- We would like to go live with Android and iOS, but it would be acceptable to start with only one of them.
- No credit card information will be stored by the application; a payment gateway like PayPal should by in charge of the actual money movement.

**Why am I asking this?**

Someone is asking me to develop an iOS or Android application for allowing his cutomers to add money into their customer cards.

**Details of the application requeriment:**

- This service would be available only in the US.
- The application will cost a fix amount to download.
- It is initially required for iOS or Android but off course, bb's and why not wp7 could need to be supported soon.

Searching Stack Overflow and then the web I came to the feeling of Apple and Google being restrictive to this kind of applications, I also would like to know if it is true.

**Example**

I've found [Starbucks' mobile app](http://money.cnn.com/galleries/2011/technology/1101/gallery.mobile_payments/index.html) to be a very good example of what I need as the link says: *To reload the card, customers can link it to a debit, credit card or PayPal account*

I wonder if doing that is possible for any application or if there is a commercial agreement between Starbucks and Apple behind.

Answer (score 2):

you can provide payment support in two ways ,

step 1 :By Inbuilt API's from Payment Comps like Paypal,CHASE etc.

Its easy & also security concerns are managed by provider & no need to write server side code but it is limited to certain features , where we can't customize it to our needs to a max level

step 2 : you need a create a server side API like iPhone - Server API - Payment System - got back response - pass result to iphone through server api as status.

where step 2 will needs server side support like php or any other & its highly customizable but security concerns we need to manage ourself.

Regarding App Submission , i dont see any rigorous measures in both plateform as we have submitted nearly 10 ecommerce apps.

so decide which kind of you want to use.

There's still a lot but i m not aware of them - still learning ....